# error trying to print data when a variable is true

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am making an application to divide expenses where after adding an bill you have to add expenses or transfers depending on what you want to do when you want to add either of the two you have to fill in this information title, description, amount, who paid and the date You must also decide whether or not it is a transfer and when confirming it you should return to the previous one and those data will be printed. but when it is a transfer the data is not printed and I can't find why

este es el repo https://github.com/lautaro-tomas-ardiles/SplitOfExpenses.git

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

these are the error files

```
package com.example.diviciondegastos.screens

import androidx.compose.foundation.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.*
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.ArrowBack
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.drawBehind
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Offset
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.*
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.*
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import com.example.diviciondegastos.R
import com.example.diviciondegastos.navegation.AppScreens

data class ExpenseData(val typeElement: Boolean, val account: Double, val date: String, val description: String, val transfer: Double)

val data = arrayListOf<ExpenseData>()

@Composable
fun MainExpensesA(navController: NavController){
    Scaffold ( topBar = {
        TopAppBar(
            backgroundColor = Color(0xFF1F1F1F),
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(142.dp)
                .drawBehind {
                    drawLine(
                        color = Color(0xFFE7B85D),
                        start = Offset(0f, size.height),
                        end = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height),
                        strokeWidth = 6f,
                        cap = StrokeCap.Round
                    )
                }
        ) {
            Column {
                Row {
                    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack,
                        contentDescription = "d",
                        tint = Color.White,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .clickable {
                                navController.navigate(route = AppScreens.MainPage.route)
                            }
                            .padding(20.dp)
                            .width(24.dp)
                    )
                    Column {
                        Text(
                            text = selectedTitleAndDescription[0],
                            fontSize = 20.sp,
                            fontWeight = FontWeight(500),
                            color = Color.White
                        )
                        Text(
                            text = selectedTitleAndDescription[1],
                            fontSize = 20.sp,
                            fontWeight = FontWeight(500),
                            color = Color.White
                        )
                    }
                }
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp))
                Row {
                    Column (Modifier.absolutePadding(35.dp)) {
                        Icon(painter = painterResource(R.drawable.validando_ticket),
                            contentDescription = "factura",
                            Modifier
                                .width(48.dp)
                                .height(42.dp)
                        )
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp))
                        Text(
                            text = "Gastos",
                            fontSize = 16.sp,
                            color = Color.White
                        )
                    }
                    Spacer(Modifier.padding(105.dp))
                    Column (modifier = Modifier .absolutePadding(right = 0.dp)) {
                        Icon(painter = painterResource(R.drawable.group_2),
                            contentDescription = "saldos")
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp))
                        Text(
                            text = "Saldos",
                            fontSize = 16.sp,
                            color = Color.White
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }){
        Scaffold ( bottomBar = {
            BottomAppBar(
                backgroundColor = Color(0xFF1F1F1F)
            ) {
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(80.dp))
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(R.drawable.mas),
                    contentDescription = "image description",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(75.dp)
                        .clickable {
                            navController.navigate(route = AppScreens.NewExpenses.route)
                        }
                        .padding(vertical = 2.dp)
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(28.dp))
                var totalBill = 0.0
                    for (expense in data) {
                            totalBill += expense.account
                    }

                Column {
                    Text(
                        text = "gasto total",
                        fontSize = 16.sp
                    )
                    Text(
                        text = "$${totalBill}",
                        fontSize = 16.sp,

                    )
                }
            }
        }){
            MyExpensesDataA(data)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyExpensesDataA(elements: List<ExpenseData>) {
    LazyColumn {
        items (elements) { elements ->
            ComponentA(elements)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ComponentA(elements: ExpenseData){
    Row (modifier = Modifier
        .background(color = Color(0xFF171717))
        .drawBehind {
            drawLine(
                color = Color(0xFF424242),
                start = Offset(0f, size.height),
                end = Offset(size.width, size.height),
                strokeWidth = 6f,
                cap = StrokeCap.Round
            )
        }
        .padding(13.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        TextA(elements)
    }
}

@Composable
fun TextA(elements: ExpenseData){
    Row{
        Column {
            Text(if (elements.typeElement) "trsnferencia" else "gasto",
                color = Color.White,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle1
            )

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp))

            Text(elements.description,
                color = Color.White,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle2
            )
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))
            Column {
                Text("$" + if (elements.typeElement) elements.transfer else elements.account,
                    color = Color.White,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle1
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp))
                Text(elements.date,
                    color = Color.White,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle2
                )
        }
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.diviciondegastos.screens

import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.ArrowBack
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.ArrowDropDown
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Check
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.drawBehind
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Offset
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.StrokeCap
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.KeyboardType
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.*
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import com.example.diviciondegastos.navegation.AppScreens

var descriptionGeneralOfExpenses = ""
var billGeneralOfExpenses = 0.0
var tranferenceOfExpenses = 0.0
var dateGeneralOfExpenses = ""
var paidByGeneralOfExpenses = ""
var isTransferOfExpenses = true
var void = false

@Composable
fun NewExpenses(navController: NavController){
    Scaffold(topBar = {
        TopAppBar(
            backgroundColor = Color(0xFF1F1F1F)
        ) {
            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack,
                contentDescription = "d",
                tint = Color.White,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .clickable {
                        navController.navigate(route = AppScreens.MainExpensesA.route)
                    }
                    .padding(10.dp)
            )
            Text(
                text = "Nuevo gasto",
                fontSize = 24.sp,
                color = Color.White,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .absolutePadding(left = 7.dp)
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(70.dp))
            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Check,
                contentDescription = "d",
                tint = Color.White,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .clickable {
                        navController.navigate(route = AppScreens.MainExpensesA.route)
                        if (void) {
                            data.add(ExpenseData(isTransferOfExpenses, billGeneralOfExpenses,
                                dateGeneralOfExpenses, descriptionGeneralOfExpenses, tranferenceOfExpenses))
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(10.dp)
            )
        }
    }){
        Column {
            TextFieldN()
            ForWhom()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TextFieldN(){
    var description by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var amount by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var date by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var paidBy by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var showDropdownMenu by remember { mutableStateOf(false)}
    var isTransfer by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    Column (modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 65.dp,end = 65.dp, top = 10.dp, bottom = 5.dp)) {
        Column {
            Row {
                Text(" es trasferencia o gasto ",
                    fontSize = 20.sp,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 7.dp)
                )
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowDropDown,
                    contentDescription = "Dropdown Icon",
                    tint = Color.White,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .clickable {
                            showDropdownMenu = true
                        }
                )
            }
            DropdownMenu(
                expanded = showDropdownMenu,
                onDismissRequest = { showDropdownMenu = false }
            ) {
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    onClick = {
                        isTransfer = true
                        showDropdownMenu = false
                    }
                ) {
                    Text("Transferencia")
                }
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    onClick = {
                        isTransfer = false
                        showDropdownMenu = false
                    }
                ) {
                    Text("Gasto")
                }
            }
        }
        isTransferOfExpenses = isTransfer
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10 .dp))
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = description,
            onValueChange = { description = it } ,
            label = { Text("descripcion") }
        )
        descriptionGeneralOfExpenses = description
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = amount,
            onValueChange = { amount = it },
            label = { Text("monto") },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number
            )
        )
        if (isTransfer){
            tranferenceOfExpenses = if (amount.isNotEmpty()) amount.toDouble() else 0.0
            billGeneralOfExpenses = 0.0
        }else{
            billGeneralOfExpenses = if (amount.isNotEmpty()) amount.toDouble() else 0.0
            tranferenceOfExpenses = 0.0
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = date,
            onValueChange = { date = it } ,
            label = { Text("fecha (dd/mm/aa)") }
        )
        dateGeneralOfExpenses = date
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10 .dp))
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = paidBy,
            onValueChange = { paidBy = it } ,
            label = { Text("pagado por") }
        )
        paidByGeneralOfExpenses = paidBy
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10 .dp))
    }
    void = descriptionGeneralOfExpenses != "" && billGeneralOfExpenses != 0.0 && dateGeneralOfExpenses != "" && paidByGeneralOfExpenses != ""
}

@Composable
fun ForWhom() {
    Row(modifier = Modifier
        .background(Color(0xFF1F1F1F))
        .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Para quien",
            fontSize = 23.sp,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 13.dp, horizontal = 15.dp)
        )
    }
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp) )
    for(x in selectedParticipants){
        Row (
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(0.dp,4.dp,0.dp,0.dp)
                .height(37.dp)
                .drawBehind {
                    drawLine(
                        color = Color(0xFF424242),
                        start = Offset(0f, size.height),
                        end = Offset(size.width, size.height),
                        strokeWidth = 3f,
                        cap = StrokeCap.Round
                    )
                }
        ) {
            Text(
                text = x,
                fontSize = 22.sp,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 50.dp, vertical = 2.dp),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center
            )
        }
    }
}
```